# SQL Server - Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Input Data

```
ID    Value1    Value2    Value3    Value4
100    10        ABC       15:00     4551
100    20        DEF       18:00     4556
103    30        XYZ       13:00     5667
103    40        TTT       11:00     4789
```

Desired Result

```
ID    Result1    Result2   Result3   Result4
100    10        ABC       15:00     4551, 4556
103    40        TTT       11:00     5667, 4789
```

I want to group input data by ID. Result 1, Result 2 and Result 3 columns should be values from row with minimum Value3. And Result 4 should be concatenation of Value 4.

Can I do this without cursors and loops.

Comment: You can concatenate Value4 with "FOR XML PATH".   Examples on the web abound.  For the other columns, Partition by ID and Order by Value3 and get row_number 1 for each partition.   There may be better ways, but that's the first thing that came off the top of my head that I am sure will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work i think.
The `tmpTable` is just for example data.
The `partition by` is for the min values.
But i think the XML part could be... better.

```
WITH tmpTable (ID, Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4) AS 
    (
    SELECT 100, 10, 'ABC', '15:00', 4551 UNION 
    SELECT 100, 20, 'DEF', '18:00', 4556 UNION 
    SELECT 103, 30, 'XYZ', '13:00', 5667 UNION 
    SELECT 103, 40, 'TTT', '11:00', 4789
    )

SELECT 
    ID, Value1 AS Result1, Value2 AS Result2, Value3 AS Result3, 
    Result4 = SubString((SELECT ', ' + sub.Value4 
                         FROM (SELECT Top 100000 Convert(VARCHAR(255), tmpTable.Value4) AS Value4
                               FROM tmpTable
                               WHERE tmpTable.ID = data.ID
                               ORDER BY tmpTable.Value4 ASC) sub
                         FOR XML path('')), 3, 1000000)
FROM (  
    SELECT *, sort = Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Value3 ASC)
    FROM tmpTable
    ) data
WHERE sort = 1
```

The Result:

```
ID    Result1   Result2   Result3   Result4
100   10        ABC       15:00     4551, 4556
103   40        TTT       11:00     4789, 5667
```